# What makes you think I would just run away?

Tags: verbs, tenses

In Lost Dasmond talks to his future father in law and tells him the following:

> What makes you think that I would run away.

I was wondering what tense it was and why 'would' not 'will'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Would* here is an example of what is traditionally called the Second Conditional, and indicates the likely outcome of a hypothetical situation. I don't know Lost, but I'm assuming that Dasmond is confined in some way and saying something like:

- What makes you think that I would run away if I had the chance?

The sentence:

- What makes you think that I will run away?

contains no hypothetical aspect. Dasmond's interlocutor thinks that Dasmond is going to run away and Dasmond wants to know why.

---

EDIT

On further reflection, it is indeed possible to construe the sentence:

- What makes you think that I will run away?

as hypothetical, using the First Conditional.

- What makes you think I will run away if I get the chance.

So the usual principles apply when choosing the conditional 1 over the conditional 2. Namely that the conditional 2 implies that the possibility (in this case) of escaping confinement is more remote.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense now. And I also heard this where Jack(an actor in the series) asks the lady about a secret and she tells her: "I can't, because he wouldn't want me to." Any thoughts on this one? Why can't she say: He doesnt want me to or He didnt want me to?

Comment: If you know that she doesn't want you to say it (e.g. because she has told you this), then use *because she doesn't want me to.* If you  don't know it, then use *because she wouldn't want me to* to imply that you are sure she would say no if you were to ask her permission to reveal the secret. [Good luck in your tenacious efforts to understand the multiple facets of the word *would*!]

Comment: Again its the hypothetical.  The lady doesn't know for a fact that he doesn't want her to because she hasn't actually asked if it's okay but she supposes that if she were to ask he would say, "No."

Comment: Thank you. One last question. The first guy who has told the secret is dead. Can we still use 'doesn't'. And why would we use 'would' in questions most of the time for example: Would you tell me who that man is?(Do we have to answer this with would, or can we answer in other structures as well?) I wouldnt know him, I dont know him, I wouldnt tell you, I won't tell you. What is the difference? Sorry to be so verbose.

Comment: @Noah, your one last question seems like several to me! I recommend posting each specific question separately. There's certainly not enough space to answer them in a comment.

Comment: @Shoe- Sorry for that, I will do that. But you didn't answer the first part of the question(s).

Comment: @Noah, If the secret-teller is dead, then you would need to say: *Sorry, he didn't want me to tell you.*

Comment: @Shoe- Thank you. And the 'would' case stays the same no matter if he is dead or not, right?

Comment: @Noah, Yes, If you didn't ask the dead secret-teller if you could reveal her secret, but are sure she would have said No had you done so, then you would say: *She wouldn't want me to tell you* or *She wouldn't have wanted me to tell you*. Which of these is better could be the subject of a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this sensibly we need to know what went before. It may be as Shoe says, but there’s another way of looking at it, and that’s as reported speech. The person addressed says ‘I think you will run away’. Although the speaker responds with a question, he is still reporting what the first speaker said. When speech is reported, the time indicated by the verb is shifted backwards. In cases such as this, ‘would’ can be seen as the past tense of ‘will’, and that may be why it’s used here.

Comment: Barrie, I agree that it is common to backshift from *will* to *would* when reporting thinking after the fact. So *I think you will run away*  becomes *I thought you would run away* when reported. However, in the OP's sentence the main clause (*What makes you think*) is in the present tense, and it is not usual to backshift in such circumstances. For example, if someone asks you every day : *Will you run away?* you do not change *will* to *would* when reporting to another person. You would say, for example: "*He's always asking if I will run away.*

Comment: @Shoe: You're right and I had thought of that. Ideally, either ‘What made you think that I would run away’ or ‘What makes you think that I will run away.’ As I said, we need the full context to know what was intended.